# How to load different stylesheets depending on the previous URL

Tags: php, css

Our business network uses the same PHP booking system for each venue and all of our online bookings. At the moment, the booking system is styled in a really bland fashion, and as all of our venues have their own website, with their own styles, there is no continuity when clicking "book now" from a site, and loading the booking system.

I'm wondering if there is a way that we can put some javascript on the booking system landing page, that can load external stylesheets, depending on which URL the customer clicked through from.

Ideally something like

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.search.indexOf('example1.co.uk') === 0)
    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style1.css\" />");
</script>

<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
if(window.location.search.indexOf('example2.co.uk') === 0)
    document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style2.css\" />");
</script>
```

This doesn't seem to work though. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Use Sessions in PHP to track what stylesheets you want to display

Comment: Are you getting any error messages or are you simply not getting the results you want?

Comment: Do you have control over the venue sites too? If so just pass a query string with the correct CSS sheet in the link itself. Relying on getting the information after the click isn't always going to work.

Comment: Populus - Won't php sessions be deleted after the leaving the website with the book now button? unfortunately the booking system is on another server.
Levi Hackwith - No error messages, just nothings happening.
Rick Calder - Good idea, ill give it a crack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your question correctly you should have control over the venues sites as well? If this is the case pass a querystring identifying the CSS sheet you want to use from the original link.

Something like:

```
<a href="http://booking_system.com/?css=1">Click to book</a>
```

Then it's a simple as running a php switch statement depending on the result.

```
<?php
$css = $_GET['css'];

switch ($css) {
    case 1:
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style1.css" />';
    break;
    case 2:
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style2.css" />';
    break;
    default:
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="default.css" />';
    break;
}
?>
```

You could even store the $css in a PHP session to retain it if you have to change pages on the booking system site.

Obviously this only works if you have control over the links on the venues sites, but it is far more predictable and reliable than trying to get the referrer after the fact.

Answer (score 1):

Try `document.referrer`. This will get you the previous browser URL if the user clicked on a link to reach to the current page.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like:

```
<?php
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == "example2.co.uk") {
    print("<link rel=\"stylesheet\" type=\"text/css\" href=\"style2.css\" />");
}
?>
```

You could then dump the above code into the <head> section of your site.

Comment: ooh, i like the look of that. Ill give it a go. The main problem i have is that im not in control of the booking system, just the venue sites, so i have to wait for this other guy to upload it before i can test it!

Comment: Relying on the referrer isn't a great option, as user agents are not required to send it along with the page request.  For instance, if you click on a link for the purpose of opening it in a new window or tab, there is no referrer.